# surefire not picking up properties file

Tags: java, maven-2, surefire

Hi I have module inside a project which i'm trying to run from the modules directory as such:

mvn integration-test -PmyProps

in pom

```
<properties>
                <user>admin</user>

</properties
```

in src/test/resources/test.properties

```
 user=${user}
```

When i execute the test i get `user={user} instead of user=admin`

If i run it via intellij or eclipse i have no problems with it and properties get picked up?

is it because the property values are getting assigned to the target directory?

This is the class loader:

InputStream testPropertiesInput = WebDriverConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("smoke.properties");

i've tried making it "target/classes/smoke.properties" but no luck.

Comment: Maven properties and Proerties in a file are different. You have to use Filtering, as stated by khmarbaise. However, you should use a Unit Test dedicated property file (in src/test/resources) for your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

First if you have unit tests which seemed to be in your case use simply:

mvn test

furthermore to get resource files beeing [filtered](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) you need to active filtering

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>...</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
   ...
</build>
```